# Logstash: Feed whole file and create a new event by splitting with newline character

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have the following logstash configuration for reading syslog-like messages from kafka:

```
input {
    kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => "172.24.0.3:9092"
        topics => ["test"]
    }
}
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP}" }
    }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

So, when a syslog-line is sent at logstash input the following message is generated at stdout:

**FROM KAFKA**

```
r = p1.send('test', b'Jul 16 09:07:47 ubuntu user: test500')
```

**STDOUT**

```
{
       "message" => "Jul 16 09:07:47 ubuntu user: test500",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => 2018-07-16T12:29:57.854Z,
          "host" => "6d87dde4c74e"
}
```

Now, I would like to add multiple lines with `\n` character at the end of each line and logstash processes the input as two separated messages so that the logstash stdout to be similar to the following example:

**MULTIPLE LINES FROM KAFKA IN THE SAME MESSAGE**

```
r = p1.send('test', b'Jul 16 09:07:47 ubuntu user: test501\nJul 16 09:07:47 ubuntu user: test502')
```

**DESIRED STDOUT**

```
{
       "message" => "Jul 16 09:07:47 ubuntu user: test501",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => 2018-07-16T12:29:57.854Z,
          "host" => "6d87dde4c74e"
}
{
       "message" => "Jul 16 09:07:47 ubuntu user: test502",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => 2018-07-16T12:29:57.854Z,
          "host" => "6d87dde4c74e"
}
```

Any ideas how to achieve this behavior on logstash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve the behavior I described above by using line codec:

```
input {
    kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => "172.24.0.3:9092"
        topics => ["test"]
        ## ## ## ## ## 
        codec => line
        ## ## ## ## ##
    }
    stdin {}
}
```